# how i can change the directory of files

Tags: php, file, gzip

I have a script which gzipping the files but  then i want to move those gzipped files to another location .Here is my code ;

```
function gzCompressFile($source, $level = 9){ 
$dest = $source . '.gz'; 
$mode = 'wb' . $level; 
$error = false; 
if ($fp_out = gzopen($dest, $mode)) { 
    if ($fp_in = fopen($source,'rb')) { 
        while (!feof($fp_in)) 
            gzwrite($fp_out, fread($fp_in, 1024 * 512)); 
        fclose($fp_in); 
    } else {
        $error = true; 
    }
    gzclose($fp_out); 
} else {
    $error = true; 
}
if ($error)
    return false; 
else
    return $dest; 
}
```

files located => public/export,

files gzipped to =>public,

where i want  files  gzipped =>public/backup

Basically i want gzipped files to move at backup folder.

Comment: Try `rename`, it also moves files to other directories.

Comment: Please forgive my lack of knowledge  i am new here ,  i tried rename and i recieved access denied error.

Comment: You might not have write permissions to the target.

Answer (score 3):

You can use rename function.

Syntax :-

```
rename(CURRENT_PATH, DESTINATION_PATH);
```